# Change context menu shortcuts in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms, contextmenu

SSMS (2012, 2014) has a very handy feature for viewing/copying definitions.

When you right-click on a view, you can simply press **S**->**C**->**N** on your keyboard and get the script opened. Instead of navigating Script -> Create -> NewQuery,

[image]

Same applies if you want to Alter view (S->A->N) or copy its' definition to clipboard (S->A->C).

Problem: due to a very strange reason - probably MS run out of symbols - the same combination (S->A->C) on *Stored procedures* opens a View Facets window.

Question1: what is the combination for altering a Stored procedure and copying the definition into clipboard?
Pressing "Y" for Modify is OK, but it won't copy.

Question2: is it possible to configure these shortcuts?

Thanks,

Constantine.